# Local Storage Null Error in JS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to make an HTML, CSS, and JS website that asks the user questions on index.html, and based on the values the script matches a cable/cables and displays the match(es) on results.html.

Heres my main.js linked to my index.html site:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentQuestion = 1;
    var selectedUsage = "";
    var selectedShape = "";
    var selectedPins = "";

    var cables = [
        {
            name: "HDMI",
            shape: "D Shaped",
            pinNumber: "0",
            usage: "Video"
        },

        {
            name: "USB",
            shape: "Rectangular",
            pinNumber: "0",
            usage: "Peripherals"
        }
        // Add more cable objects here
    ];

    function showQuestion(questionNumber) {
        $('.question').hide();
        $('#question' + questionNumber).fadeIn(500);
    }

    function displayResult() {
        console.log("selectedUsage:", selectedUsage);
        console.log("selectedShape:", selectedShape);
        console.log("selectedPins:", selectedPins);

        var matches = cables.filter(function(cable) {
            return cable.usage.toLowerCase() === selectedUsage.toLowerCase() &&
                   cable.shape.toLowerCase() === selectedShape.toLowerCase() &&
                   cable.pinNumber === selectedPins;
        });

        console.log("matches:", matches);

        if (matches.length > 0) {
            var resultText = "Identified Cable:\n";
            matches.forEach(function(match) {
                resultText += `${match.name} Cable\n`;
            });
            $('#result-text').text(resultText);
        } else {
            $('#result-text').text('No matching cables found.');
        }

        // Removed the redirect to results.html from here
    }

    showQuestion(currentQuestion);

    $('.usage-button').on('click', function () {
        currentQuestion++;
        if (currentQuestion === 2) {
            selectedUsage = $(this).text();
            showQuestion(currentQuestion);
        } else {
            var usage = $(this).text();
            $('#question1').fadeOut(500, function () {
                $('#question2').fadeIn(500);
            });
            $('#result').fadeOut(500, function () {
                selectedUsage = usage;
                displayResult();
                localStorage.setItem('selectedUsage', selectedUsage);
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('selectedUsage')); // Check selectedUsage in localStorage
                window.location.replace("results.html"); // Redirect here
            });
        }
    });

    $('.shape-button').on('click', function () {
        currentQuestion++;
        if (currentQuestion === 3) {
            selectedShape = $(this).text();
            showQuestion(currentQuestion);
        } else {
            var shape = $(this).text();
            $('#question2').fadeOut(500, function () {
                $('#question3').fadeIn(500);
            });
            $('#result').fadeOut(500, function () {
                selectedShape = shape;
                displayResult();
                localStorage.setItem('selectedShape', selectedShape);
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('selectedShape')); // Check selectedShape in localStorage
                window.location.replace("results.html"); // Redirect here
            });
        }
    });

    $('.pin-button').on('click', function () {
        selectedPins = $(this).text();
        $('#question3').fadeOut(500, function () {
            displayResult();
            localStorage.setItem('selectedPins', selectedPins);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('selectedPins')); // Check selectedPins in localStorage
            window.location.replace("results.html"); // Redirect here
        });
    });
});
```

And here's my JS linked with my results.html page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedUsage = localStorage.getItem('selectedUsage');
    console.log(selectedUsage)
    var selectedShape = localStorage.getItem('selectedShape');
    console.log(selectedShape)
    var selectedPins = localStorage.getItem('selectedPins');
    console.log(selectedPins)

    if (selectedUsage === null || selectedShape === null || selectedPins === null) {
        // Handle the case where one of the values is not set
        $('#result-text').text('No matching cables found.');
    } else {
        var cables = [
            {
                name: "HDMI",
                shape: "D Shaped",
                pinNumber: "0",
                usage: "Video"
            },
            // Add more cable objects here
        ];

        function displayResult() {
            var matches = cables.filter(function(cable) {
                return cable.usage.toLowerCase() === selectedUsage.toLowerCase() &&
                       cable.shape.toLowerCase() === selectedShape.toLowerCase() &&
                       cable.pinNumber === selectedPins;
            });

            if (matches.length > 0) {
                var resultText = "Identified Cable:<br>";
                matches.forEach(function(match) {
                    resultText += `${match.name} Cable<br>`;
                });
                $('#result-text').html(resultText);
            } else {
                $('#result-text').html('No matching cables found.');
            }
        }

        if ($('#result-text').length) {
            displayResult();
        }
    }
});
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="quiz-container">


        <div id="question1" class="question">
            <h2>What is the cable used for?</h2>
            <ul class="button-list">
                <li><button class="usage-button">Audio</button></li>
                <li><button class="usage-button">Video</button></li>
                <li><button class="usage-button">Peripherals</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div id="question2" class="question">
            <h2>What shape is the connector?</h2>
            <ul class="button-list">
                <li><button class="shape-button">Square</button></li>
                <li><button class="shape-button">Rectangular</button></li>
                <li><button class="shape-button">Round</button></li>
                <li><button class="shape-button">D Shaped</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div id="question3" class="question">
            <h2>How many pins does it have?</h2>
            <ul class="button-list">
                <li><button class="pin-button">0</button></li>
                <li><button class="pin-button">1</button></li>
                <li><button class="pin-button">2</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
                
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div id="result" class="question">
            <h2>Identification Result:</h2>
            <p id="result-text">Identified Cable: N/A</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my results.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Results Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result-container"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="results.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally my style.css:

```
body {
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

#quiz-container {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Style for buttons */
button {
    background-color: #FFFFFF; /* Make buttons white */
    color: #2196F3; /* Text color blue */
    padding: 15px 30px; /* Adjusted button size */
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #1565C0; /* Darker blue on hover */
    color: #FFFFFF; /* Text color white on hover */
}

/* Remove list styles for <ul> elements */
.button-list {
    list-style: none;
}

/* Ensure buttons fit on the screen without scrolling */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    button {
        padding: 10px 20px; /* Adjusted button size for smaller screens */
    }
}
```

When you open the website, the results.html at the end is completely blank, even though it should say that it has matches and says them, or doesn't have matches.

I tried using console.log to see where the code was stopping or skipping yet I didn't get anything. I also tried unexpected DOM breakpoints, and still nothing. I was expecting there to be an error, yet it seems to be a logic error. I have also quadruple checked the docs, and haven't seen any fallacies. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: so in results.html, you always get `$('#result-text').text('No matching cables found.');`? oh, wait, there's no such element with id `result-text` in `results.html` ... so, you'd get no indication of anything - what makes you say anything is null?

Comment: My bad, looks like I accidentally deleted the line, but when I have it, it still shows no cables matching and the variables in log are defined as null.

Comment: Your code is too complicated :(( however, I found out that your `else`  blocks for `.usage-button` and `.shape-button` event listeners, never get executed. I think your implementation for the if statement has a bug (honestly, I feel you are making it too complicated. try to rethink about the implmentation design)

Comment: Thank you, I do tend to get cluttered sometimes 